# otool -l shows (0x80000022) Unknown load command on OSX 10.5 when framework was built from OSX 10.6

Tags: macos, frameworks, osx-leopard, otool

I built a framework using OSX 10.6 and everything is fine, I have the Base SDK and Deployment SDK set to 10.5.  I also am building only a i386 arch.

When I bring this framework to a OSX 10.5 and I run otool -l on it I get the following results:

"Load command 6
      cmd ?(0x80000022) Unknown load command"

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the or'ed in bit (0x80000000) on the load command message:

```
"Load command 6 cmd ?(0x80000022) Unknown load command"
```

means that the command is required, and then I found out that my base SDK was not set correctly, and once I corrected that and the deployment target to 10.5, I got (0x00000022) instead which means its not required so it's weak linked and doesn't cause any problems.

So my problem was a mistake by me, but I added some information on how to read the failures so hopefully this is useful to someone else.